# FFmpeg build using Eclipse - Linux

Tags: linux, eclipse, ffmpeg

I am trying to import ffmpeg source into Eclipse on Linux. I have followed every step mentioned at 
https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Setup_Ecli ... peg_(Linux)

But When i try to create a new project in Eclipse , I am not able to import it as a Makefile project . 
I do not see any option in my Eclipse Indigo import wizard as ""C/C++" and then "Makefile Project with Existing Code"

Any pointers on how to create a Eclipse project from ffmpeg source taken from git repository.

Details-
Linux Ubuntu 11.10
Eclipse Indigo version 3.7.0
ffmpeg 2.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some more tinkering, Got the Eclipse to build ffmpeg source.

1] While creating a project from Makefile, its important to point to the folder having the ffmpeg src, mak files cloned from repository, instead of the option of using default location.

2] Selected GNU Autotools as the toolchain for this project while creating the project.

After this the fmmpeg was built correctly in eclipse and necessary ffmpeg executables generated.